# after using token interceptor in my application getting exception

Tags: struts2

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="appDefault">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
      <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
      <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param> 
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession">
   <param name="includeMethods">upload,view,delete,confirm</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 

    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png,image/pjpeg,application  /pdf</param>
    <param name="maximumSize">1048576</param>
   </interceptor-ref> 

  </interceptor-stack>

</interceptors>

<default-interceptor-ref name="appDefault" />

<action name="upload_*" class="nic.rto.sow4.actions.UploadAction" method="{1}">
      ----
      -----
   <result name="invalid.token">/jsp/invalid_token.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

This exception occurred:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:407)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:914)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure interceptor for individual action as given below.

```
<action name="yourAction" class="com.YourActionClass">
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/update.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: i have written  inside interceptor- stack .if  i have removed this token interceptor in my application  its working fine... is there any other solution to prevent multiform submission without using token interceptor?

Comment: Have you added `<s:token/>` tag inside your form.